# How to make @key options work with <v-list>?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

`@keypress`, `@keydown` & `@keyup` do not seem to work for `<v-list>`.

They work fine with other elements such as `<v-text-field>`, for example.

```
<template>
  <div id="my-list">
    <v-list dense @keypress.shift="test()">
      <v-list-item-group 
        v-model="selected"
        :multiple="multiple"
        color="red"
      >
        <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in itemList" :key="i">
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyList",
  components: {
    //
  },

  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    multiple: false,
    itemList: [
      { name: "My Item 1" },
      { name: "My Item 2" },
      { name: "My Item 3" },
      { name: "My Item 4" },
      { name: "My Item 5" },
      { name: "My Item 6" },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("TEST");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried with `<v-list-item-group>` & `<v-list-item>`, but it didn't work either.

When you press, in this case, `Shift`, absolutely nothing happens - no errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `@key<X>.<Y>.native`, where `X` is either `down` or `up` (not sure about `press`) and `Y` is one of the keyboard buttons.

Examples: `@keydown.ctrl.native`, `@keyup.alt.native`, `@keyup.shift.native`, `@keydown.shift.native`, etc.

It works with `<v-list>`, `<v-list-item-group>` and `<v-list-item>`, BUT for some reason you need to maintain the click in order for it to work, i.e. pressing/releasing one of the keyboard buttons while you're still holding the mouse button down.

P.S. If you want to add a function of, for example, `Ctrl+Click`, you need to use `@click.ctrl="myFunction()"` (will only get called **after** you let go of the mouse button) or `@mousedown.ctrl="myFunction()"` (will get called immediately upon clicking, regardless of whether you hold down the mouse button or not).